# is dotnetcore code coverage available for tfs 2017

Tags: c#, code-coverage

Is there support for code coverage on tfs 2017 using dotnetcore?

If so are there any instructions? I am unable to find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code coverage and other data collection is **not supported** yet,  no agent support.

> We are fixing this issue as part of this
>   https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/pull/1149/files Will update
>   the thread once fix is gone and new agent is released. thread
>   https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/579#issuecomment-324401462
>
> Source Link: [**VSTest task fails to execute tests in .NET Core 2.0 test project**](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/5066)